# Set a (semi) default message in a custom exception class

Tags: powershell, class

I wish to create a custom exception in PowerShell with a message that is almost default, but which contains some of the the other parameters passed to the exception.

The closest I have gotten is as below, but this fails with the following error -

> 'Message' is a ReadOnly property.

Is it possible to set a (semi) default message in this way?

```
class InvalidEnvironmentException : System.Exception
{
    [string]$Version
    [string]$Environment
    [string[]]$VersionTags

    InvalidEnvironmentException($Version, $Environment, $VersionTags) : base(){
        $this.Message = "Package version '{0}' cannont be deployed to environment '{1}'." -f $Version, $Environment
        $this.VersionTags = $VersionTags
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your custom message to the base constructor:

```
class InvalidEnvironmentException : System.Exception
{
    [string]$Version
    [string]$Environment
    [string[]]$VersionTags

    InvalidEnvironmentException($Version, $Environment, $VersionTags) : base(("Package version '{0}' cannont be deployed to environment '{1}'." -f $Version, $Environment))
    {
        $this.Environment = $Environment
        $this.Version = $Version
        $this.VersionTags = $VersionTags
    }
}
```